# Ag-grid React column shifts that uses valueGetter when rowData fetched from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Whenever I fetch data from any server to display it in ag-grid, ag-grid does not maintain the column order for the column that uses valueGetter to choose the value and puts that column automatically at the end.

**The problem is replicated in the following code sandbox link:** https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-column-ordering-bug-bz055 **as a minimum reproducible example**

The data received from the server is in the following format

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
```

The table in the code wants to display the only 4 columns in the following order:

1. name
2. **company.name**
3. email
4. phone

However, as you can see in the CodeSandbox link, when `company name` value is retrieved using valueGetter in the column definition, it automatically displays `company name` as the last column.

How can this be fixed? Any Help will be appreciated?

**Note: I can call the ag-grid gridApi or columnApi to reset columns in onGridReady, this fixes it, but it seems like a hack. Is there a better way to accomplish this**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the column does not have a `field` supplied, I'd recommend either supplying a `field` or `colID` to the column. This would be the simplest approach without having to use any API calls to move the column:

```
    {
      // use either or both
      colId: "companyName",
      // field: "comapnyName",
      headerName: "Company Name",
      valueGetter: (params) => {
        return params.data.company?.name;
      }
    }
```

I've forked your example showing this: https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-column-ordering-bug-forked-62ph3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks this fixed it. Can you explain why setting colId (or field for that matter) also should fix it. Actually when you provide valueGetter, doesnt the functionality of field get overridden?

Comment: The colId is a unique ID to give the column. This is optional. If missing, the ID will default to the field. If both field and colId are missing, a unique ID will be generated. This ID is used to identify the column. However, I would recommend raising your sample in the ag-grid github / zendesk channel for further investigation. It's possible that this may be a bug (will need to be investigated by the team to determine whether it is).

Comment: seems like a bug. I understand the purpose of colId and field, still doesnt seem there is a reason to shift ordering of columns if colId or field is not set. Sure I will raise the query there.

Comment: Wasted a few hours on this, great answer, thank you.